# How to detect if Xiaomi's Mi Browser using JS

Tags: javascript, web, browser-detection, responsiveness, mi

How to check using javascript if the user visiting my website is doing so using **Xiaomi's native - Mi Browser.**

Comment: [See updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65308273/295783)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [useragent](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/operating_platform/mi-a1/)

At least now, end 2023 you will need to look at `MiuiBrowser`, not just " MI "

```js
console.log(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("XiaoMi/MiuiBrowser") != -1 ? "MI browser":"Not MI browser")
```

This will show any browser on an MI phone

```js
console.log(navigator.userAgent.indexOf(" Mi ") != -1 ? "MI":"Not MI")
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return true for any Mi phone? I suggest checking specifically for `MiUiBrowser`, not just `Mi`. Here's a list of possible user agents: [MIUI Browser user agents](https://explore.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/miui-browser).

Comment: You are correct. I missed that on the useragent page since I do not actually own an XiaoMi phone